# pytest: how to ignore metafunc parameterize values for few tests in a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test written in python using pytest.
which has conftest.py for setup, which parameterize 5 account ids for each test. 
The Test Class has total 5 tests, out of which 4 needs the tests to be parameterized using metafunc (Which i have done in conftest.py), the remaining 1 test need not be parameterized. please tell how to run all these tests in one go with avoiding parameterization for the last test (test5).

my conftest.py has the following;

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
        accid = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']
        metafunc.parametrize("accid", accid)
```

my test file is named test_accid.py; which has the following;

```
    class TestAccount:
        def test_base1(self, accid):
            <test code>
        def test_base2(self, accid):
            <test code>
        def test_base3(self, accid):
            <test code>
        def test_base4(self, accid):
            <test code>

        #The following test should not have accid
        def test_no_accid(self):
            <test code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by adding the following check in conftest.py;

```
if 'accid' in metafunc.fixturenames:
    metafunc.parametrize("accid", accid)
```

So this will check if the accid is a parameter defined in test function, then only it will parameterize the test.

for my last test i removed the accid parameter, and its working now.